# Java 7 update 21 Webstart application certificate issue on windows 2008 R2

Tags: certificate, java-7, windows-server-2008-r2, java-web-start

The code is signed using a certificate( NOT self signed ) as a requirement for this java version, on Windows 7 users are prompted to run/cancel launching the application, and if they check "Do not show this message.." and run the app, it launches successfully and the certificate is added successfully to the User keystore, and the next time they launch the app, they do NOT see this message again, however on windows 2008 R2 , this is not the case, the dialog is always displayed regardless if the check "Do not show this message..", and the certificate is being correctly added to the User keystore , I tried with standard/admin users, but got the same.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: No idea. Could have to do with the default security levels for the IE used on the platform and its Java plugin, maybe? Similar thing for other browsers.

Comment: A workaround is to add the root certificate into windows trusted certificates store.